# ToolStrip vs MenuStrip - can I make their rendering identical?

Tags: .net, vb.net, toolstrip, menustrip

I need to display a toolstrip directly beneath a menustrip in my application, but setting RenderMode = Professional for each does not give identical results. They both show a background gradient, but not the same one.

Is there some way to use menustrip rendering for the toolstrip, or vice versa?
Or can someone advise how best to implement a gradient myself, that I can perform in a sub-classed renderer?

**ADDED LATER:**
Many thanks to [nobugz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/nobugz) for his answer below. Helpful material is also in  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993061/whats-the-deal-with-the-toolstrips-rendermode-property/993109#993109).
There's just one more issue -- if I base my custom renderer on the ToolStripProfessionalRenderer and override OnRenderToolstripBackground, I still get curved right-hand corners on my ToolStrip but not on my MenuStrip. Is there some internal logic that provides a different Region for filling by the background renderer? I've turned off (overridden with a do-nothing function) the border renderer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see it but can imagine it's a problem.  Override the renderer so it uses the same background renderer for both menu items and toolstrip items:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        MenuStrip1.Renderer = New MyRenderer()
    End Sub

    Private Class MyRenderer
        Inherits ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
        Protected Overrides Sub OnRenderItemBackground(ByVal e As ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs)
            MyBase.OnRenderMenuItemBackground(e)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dock two panel using `DockStyle.Top`, on top of each other, and then add a `MenuStrip` to each of them. I did the same on my app, I needed a few `MenuStrips` on rather exotical places. It can give a good result if you use a contiguos background for them.